# Detect transparency in div for .click purposes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, transparency, opaque-pointers

I've got three elements layered on top of one another, and each of them contains some transparency.  There is no transparency in the middle, just around the edges.  I want to be able to click the div in the background, but because the transparent space leading to the edge of the frontmost div is over it, instead the click event for that frontmost div fires.  I can't disable it or use stopPropegation() obviously, because the one in front still needs to be clickable.

Are there any solutions for detecting transparent space and differentiating it from opaque space?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not work, but the best I can think of - it assumes the further back divs are children of the front divs:

```
    $('div').click(function() {
        if($(this).css('opacity') != 1) {
            //it's transparent
           $(this).children('div').click();
        }
    });

    //mouse coordinates
    $('div#innerDiv').click(function(e) {
        var x = e.pageX;
        var y = e.pageY
    });
```

Comment: Oh, wait a second...I wasn't thinking, I jumped the gun with my reply saying this would work.  Is there any way to get the pixel that was clicked on the screen and then relay that to a second click to check if that second click hits anything?

Comment: Made the change - give the two "further away" divs an id, and for those check the e.pageX and e.pageY to see where the click was

Comment: I think I can piece things together from there.  Thanks!